# MySQL - INSERT ... SELECT .. FROM .. - Single transaction or transaction per row?

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction

Question:

I am currently working on a data migration. I need to migrate 2.5 million rows from one InnoDB table to another InnoDB table (with a different setup). 
I am using the following syntax to do that:

```
INSERT `new_table` (`new_column`,`more_columns`) 
SELECT `old_column`,`more_old_columns` FROM `old_table`;
```

I am wondering if MySQL/InnoDB will perform this as one giant transaction, or will MySQL/InnoDB create a transaction per row it encounters from the select? (I would basically would like to know if it will perform a COMMIT on each row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to do one monolithic transaction because if the transaction fails for any reason, mysqld will spend a long time rolling back everything from the undo logs. There are 1023 undo logs in the system tablespace file (a.k.a. ibdata1). Here is what InnoDB looks like:

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

As I said before, there are 1023 undo logs (a.k.a. Rollback Segments). The amount of info stored to preserve the state of `new_table` would fill up just one undo log. It's not worth the effort and firepower to load everything as a single transaction and a single commit loading one undo log in the event of a crash that may never happen.

Please script the retrieval from `old_table` to do something like 10000 rows at a time. Since `autocommit=1` by default, a single commit will be 10000 rows. For 2.5 million rows, that would be 250 commits.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rolando! I will script it do to 10.000 rows at a time, bash can do that perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

It will all fail or it will all be succesfull meaning one giant transaction.